# mysql like %asd% equivalent solr query

Tags: php, mysql, solr

I have a query that I am trying to process, I searched it but could not find any answer, I am doing something wrong, What I want to search is, %asd%, but I get asd% result instead of it,

my fieldtype is this,

```
<fieldType name="text_general_edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

and my query is, name:asd, is it my query or field type ? thank you :)

Comment: Edge ngram for "loved" would be "lo", "lov", "love" and "loved", which makes them useful for suggestion. I guess you must use normal ngrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a search like `%asd%`, you dont need ngram filters... Basically solr uses `~` for single char and `*` for multiple chars in their searches...

e.g 
`name:asd~` will match `asda asdb asdc` and so on while `name:asd*` will match`asdasadad asdfgkhjfgkl` and so on so you can use `name: ~asd~` to match `basdf` or `easdk` and `name:*asd*` for `aldkaasdsdfsd` or `oippopasdoppm`

you dont need ngrams for this kind of search as far as i know